# Sandboxing a program under windows

Tags: c#, sandbox

I was searching on internet for an easy way of sandboxing an application under windows. Apparently there isn't an easy way of doing it in a comnplete way. I did find an application on github that does at least a simple sandbox but I'm unsure how safe and how much it helps.

[Smaug](https://github.com/itchio/smaug) is creating a Window user with low privileges to give part of the security. I am not sure how much it helps but I believe it will allow at least to have your own files in a safe place, as long as the malicious program is not using some 0day hack that works with un privileged user.  It is safe for any simple malware-like attack I believe.

Is there some literature available about this kind of solution ? Am I overestimating its safety? I might have to find also how it's doable from .Net

edit:
I would like to be able to add this functionality to my application without anyone to install any more application since I might not be able to test all the possibilities and/or I'm not sure they will even run on it.

To make it clearer, my application is some kind of front-end to start other applications. I don't want to ask to install N applications.

Comment: And old question but does it answers yours https://superuser.com/questions/17615/windows-64bit-sandboxing-software-alternatives?

Comment: Windows 10 literally has a Sandbox feature.  Only you can determine if it satisfies your requirements though

Comment: @Ramhound I forgot to mention that. It doesn't since I can't ask every user of my program to install it.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've seen sandboxie, but 1. It seems stalled and 2. I can't really ask my users to install it. Smaug's solution seems to be the only way

Comment: So you should [edit] and clarify the question to state "I want the user of my program to install it and have it automatically sandboxed"

Comment: So you are find asking users to download Smaug but Sandboxie?  Windows Sandbox at least is a Windows feature, granted, only for Windows 10 Professional but tons of programs have that requirement

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited my question. I don't want anyone to install any sandbox application. I wanted to understand what's available and eventually implement the "create user" trick on my application.

Comment: Windows Sandbox is not a feature of every edition of Windows 10 and it must be enabled by the user.  Windows doesn't have any other sandboxing capabilities.  Running an application as a unprivileged user wouldn't gain you anything.  That is actually the default behavior of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I disagree. If you create another unprivileged user, you gain at the very least the protection against software that can steal your credentials on Firefox/Chrome/IE/Safari.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 64bit Sandboxing software alternatives](https://superuser.com/questions/17615/windows-64bit-sandboxing-software-alternatives)

Comment: @music2myear not really. I've seen that, but I was hoping there were some other solutions like in other OSes (jailing etc).